# Mark all checkboxes in UITableView with a Button Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkbox

In my UITableView "tableview" I added checkboxes in each row using UITableView default functionality.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
       }
 -(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    return 3;
 }
```

I can select only Multiple checkboxes.But I want to select all the checkboxes using a button click.I can use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to loop through all the rows and get the contents but the checkboxes stays unchecked.

```
- (IBAction)selectallbutton:(id)sender {

   NSInteger nRows=[arr count];

    for(int i=0;i<nRows;i++){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [self tableView:tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    }
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

Is it possible to check them all using this approach or should I try another way?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
- (IBAction)selectallbutton:(id)sender {

   NSInteger nRows=[arr count];

    for(int i=0;i<nRows;i++){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO]; //you can change animated:YES if needed
     }
}
```

Comment: btw there is a slight problem..the cells which are in the bottom...i mean only the ones i can see in the tableview area are marked....but when i scrolled the bottom cells ..they were unchecked...is it because of dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier?? is there anyway to check those as well?